# NullPointerException when working with ArgumentMatcher

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, matcher

I've written the following JUnit test, which uses [`ArgumentMatchers`](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html).

```
    MyClass classUnderTest = new MyClass();

    class AnyBooleanMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Boolean> {
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            return ((Boolean) argument).equals(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    class MyObjectMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<MyObject> {
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            return ((MyObject) argument).getValue().equals("123");
        }
    }

    final Service mockService = mock(Service.class);

    when(mockService.search(Matchers.argThat(new MyObjectMatcher()),
            Matchers.argThat(new AnyBooleanMatcher())));

    classUnderTest.callMethod(mock(ActionEvent.class));

    verify(mockService).search(Matchers.argThat(new MyObjectMatcher()),
            Matchers.argThat(new AnyBooleanMatcher()));
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting a `NullPointerException`, at the `when` statement.

I even know why: [`argThat`](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) returns `null`, as specified in the JavaDoc. But I don't know why my test won't work, when the ones in the [example](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) - which are modelled in exactly the same way - do work.

Comment: Where *exactly* is the NPE? The `when` statement has lots of embedded method calls - which one is causing the NPE?

Comment: I think that the NPE happens at `Matchers.argThat(new MyObjectMatcher())`. At least there it also happens when I extract this statement in a method (as recommended in the Mockito documentation). And as said, `argThat` should be definition return `null`. :-|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` because the method signature is using a native type, and you are using `Matchers.argThat`, which returns an object.

When compiled Javac will add auto-unboxing code around `Matchers.argThat(new AnyBooleanMatcher())`, as you said it returns `null`, so you have the cause of the NPE.

I'm pretty sure the Javadoc of mockito also say to use `intThat`, `booleanThat` style method when dealing with native types. Using those will prevent the auto-unboxing code introduced by the compiler.

On another topic, I would recommand you to write code like that, in order to make it more readable.

```
when(mockService.search(argThat(hasValue("123")), booleanThat(isTrue()))).thenReturn("something");

// ...

private AnyBooleanMatcher isTrue() {
    return new AnyBooleanMatcher();
}

private MyObjectMatcher hasValue(String value) {
    return new MyObjectMatcher(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The auto boxing caused the NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank You. Native Type made me realise my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `when.. thenReturn..` syntax:

```
doReturn(new AnyBooleanMatcher()).when(mockService).search(Matchers.argThat(new MyObjectMatcher());
```